# Slow printing java text method not separating lines

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a text-based game and want the text to print slowly. I created a method that does that, but when I use it for multiple strings, it doesn't separate the lines and just continues to print everything on the first line. I'm not sure exactly what I can do in this situation.

I'm really new to coding so if anyone knows a better way to make the slow printing text method on Java, please let me know.

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class adventureGame {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        slowPrint("Text text text");
        slowPrint("Text text text");
        slowPrint("Text text text");
        slowPrint("Text text text");
        slowPrint("text text text");
        slowPrint("Text text text");
    }
    public static void slowPrint(String output) {
        for (int i = 0; i<output.length(); i++) {
          char c = output.charAt(i);
          System.out.print(c);
          try {
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(100);
          }
          catch (Exception e) {
    
          }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you tell the computer to start on a new line?

Comment: not relevant here, but an empty `catch` block is calling for problems (ignored Exception == unrecognized error)

Comment: @blurfus, I tried that initially but all it did was print every letter in a new line but if you add it outside of the for loop I get the desired output but thank you for the reply I really appreciate

Comment: @user16320675, I tried to not include it but then it gave me an error, so far there's no problem so crossing my fingers there wont be one in the future either. Thanks for pointing that out though

Comment: @LevyOcampo instead of an empty catch block, put `throw new RuntimeException(e);` that way you'll see where the error is.

Comment: You would not necessarily _see_ an error because you are caching them and doing nothing with it (i.e. swallowing it - in essence, hiding them at runtime) - This is exactly why empty catch blocks should be avoided (because they hide errors and other important stuff) - that's also the point @user16320675 was trying to make.  At the very least, you should either log it or rethrow the exception so it's visible somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell the computer to move to a new line.  Perhaps the easiest way to change the code you have to do this is to add carriage return and line feed characters to the end of each line:

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class adventureGame {
  public static void main(String[] args){
    slowPrint("Text text text\r\n");
    slowPrint("Text text text\r\n");
    slowPrint("Text text text\r\n");
    slowPrint("Text text text\r\n");
    slowPrint("text text text\r\n");
    slowPrint("Text text text\r\n");
  }

  public static void slowPrint(String output) {
    for (int i = 0; i<output.length(); i++) {
      char c = output.charAt(i);
      System.out.print(c);
      try {
        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(100);
      }
      catch (Exception e) {

      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I did something very similar but instead of adding the new line to every single individual line I put it in the slowPrint method so it can do it on its own